# Proof that the leaving variable cannot be selected as the entering one in the next round

Tags: linear-programming, simplex

Using the Dantzig's pivoting rule, can it be proven that the leaving variable of one round cannot be selected as the entering variable in the next round?

Comment: If we talk primal simplex then I think you can prove that the reduced cost of the outgoing variable is such such it will not be a candidate.  Outgoing reduced cost is something like incoming reduced cost divided by pivot element.